# Dataverse.ServiceClient fails to connect to Dynamics with "Failed to lookup current organization data"

Tags: dynamics-crm, dataverse, serviceclient

I have a problem with my .NET Core 3.1 application that connects to Dynamics. The error occurs when connecting to dynamics using the [ServiceClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powerplatform.dataverse.client.serviceclient?view=dataverse-sdk-latest) class, but it does not happen all the time and is not random. I am having trouble pinpointing the cause of the issue.

This is the error message I get when the application tries to connect:

```
2023-01-16T07:22:43.189 [Error] Executed 'CreateCustomerTimelineHttpTrigger' (Failed, Id=a36dba87-30c3-4dab-93b3-7a00aeba4de3, Duration=2346ms)Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.Utils.DataverseConnectionException : Failed to connect to Dataverse
---> System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (Exception - Fault While initializing client - RefreshInstanceDetails) 
---> Exception - Fault While initializing client - RefreshInstanceDetails
---> Exception - Failed to lookup current organization data
---> A proxy type with the name msdyncrm_GetReactions has been defined by another assembly.

Current type: CrmEarlyBound.msdyncrm_GetReactionsResponse, CEP.CustomerTimeline.API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, Existing type: CrmEarlyBound.msdyncrm_GetReactionsResponse, CEP.CustomerTimeline.API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null (Parameter 'msdyncrm_GetReactions')
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
at Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.ConnectionService.GetCachedService(ConnectionService& ConnectionObject)
at Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.ConnectionService.IntilizeService(ConnectionService& ConnectionObject)
at Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.ServiceClient.CreateServiceConnection(Object externalOrgServiceProxy,AuthenticationType requestedAuthType,String hostName,String port,String orgName,NetworkCredential credential,String userId,SecureString password,String domain,String Geo,String claimsHomeRealm,Boolean useSsl,Boolean useUniqueInstance,OrganizationDetail orgDetail,String clientId,Uri redirectUri,PromptBehavior promptBehavior,OrganizationWebProxyClientAsync externalOrgWebProxyClient,String certificateThumbPrint,StoreName certificateStoreName,X509Certificate2 certificate,Uri instanceUrl,Boolean isCloned,Boolean useDefaultCreds,Version incomingOrgVersion,ILogger externalLogger,String tokenCacheStorePath)
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.Utils.DataverseConnectionException : Exception - Fault While initializing client - RefreshInstanceDetails
---> Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.Utils.DataverseOperationException : Exception - Failed to lookup current organization data
---> System.ArgumentException : A proxy type with the name msdyncrm_GetReactions has been defined by another assembly. Current type: CrmEarlyBound.msdyncrm_GetReactionsResponse, CEP.CustomerTimeline.API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, Existing type: CrmEarlyBound.msdyncrm_GetReactionsResponse, CEP.CustomerTimeline.API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null (Parameter 'msdyncrm_GetReactions')
at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.AppDomainBasedKnownProxyTypesProvider.AddTypeMapping(Assembly assembly,Type type,String proxyName)
at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.KnownProxyTypesProvider.LoadKnownTypes(Assembly assembly)
at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.KnownProxyTypesProvider.RegisterAssembly(Assembly assembly)at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.KnownProxyTypesProvider.InitializeLoadedAssemblies()
at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.AppDomainBasedKnownProxyTypesProvider..ctor()
at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.KnownProxyTypesProvider.GetInstance(Boolean supportIndividualAssemblies)
at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.ProxySerializationSurrogate.System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializationSurrogateProvider.GetObjectToSerialize(Object obj,Type targetType)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.SurrogateToDataContractType(ISerializationSurrogateProvider serializationSurrogateProvider,Object oldObj,Type surrogatedDeclaredType,Type& objType)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer,Object graph,DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer,Object graph,DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer,Object graph,DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject(XmlDictionaryWriter writer,Object graph)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryWriter writer,PartInfo part,Object graph)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeParameter(XmlDictionaryWriter writer,PartInfo part,Object graph)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeParameters(XmlDictionaryWriter writer,PartInfo[] parts,Object[] parameters)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.SerializeBody(XmlDictionaryWriter writer,MessageVersion version,String action,MessageDescription messageDescription,Object returnValue,Object[] parameters,Boolean isRequest)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.SerializeBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer,MessageVersion version,Object[] parameters,Object returnValue,Boolean isRequest)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.OperationFormatterMessage.OperationFormatterBodyWriter.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriterMessage.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.OnWriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageWriter.WriteMessage(Message message,BufferManager bufferManager,Int32 initialOffset,Int32 maxSizeQuota)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.WriteMessageAsync(Message message,Int32 maxMessageSize,BufferManager bufferManager,Int32 messageOffset)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message,Int32 maxMessageSize,BufferManager bufferManager,Int32 messageOffset)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageContent.EnsureMessageEncoded()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageContent.TryComputeLength(Int64& length)
at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.GetComputedOrBufferLength()
at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpContentHeaders.get_ContentLength()
at System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.ValidateAndNormalizeRequest(HttpRequestMessage request)
at System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at async System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()at async System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask,HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationTokenSource cts,Boolean disposeCts)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at async System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpClientRequestChannel.HttpClientChannelAsyncRequest.SendRequestAsync[TChannel](Message message,TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at async System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.RequestAsync(??)at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at async System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.RequestAsyncInternal(Message message,TimeSpan timeout)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.TaskHelpers.WaitForCompletionNoSpin[TResult](Task`1 task)at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message,TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,Boolean oneway,ProxyOperationRuntime operation,Object[] ins,Object[] outs,TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(MethodCall methodCall,ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(MethodInfo targetMethod,Object[] args)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Reflection.DispatchProxyGenerator.Invoke(Object[] args)
at generatedProxy_1.Execute(OrganizationRequest )
at Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.Connector.OrganizationWebProxyClientAsync.<>c__DisplayClass52_0.<ExecuteCore>b__0()
at Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.Connector.WebProxyClientAsync`1.ExecuteAction[TResult](Func`1 action)
at Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.Connector.OrganizationWebProxyClientAsync.ExecuteCore(OrganizationRequest request)
at Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.Connector.OrganizationWebProxyClientAsync.Execute(OrganizationRequest request)
at async Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.ConnectionService.RefreshInstanceDetails(IOrganizationService dvService,Uri uriOfInstance)
End of inner exception
at async Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.ConnectionService.RefreshInstanceDetails(IOrganizationService dvService,Uri uriOfInstance)
End of inner exception
at async Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.ConnectionService.RefreshInstanceDetails(IOrganizationService dvService,Uri uriOfInstance)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at async Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.ConnectionService.DoDirectLoginAsync(Boolean IsOnPrem)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at async Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.ConnectionService.InitServiceAsync()<---
End of inner exception
at Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.ServiceClient.CreateServiceConnection(Object externalOrgServiceProxy,AuthenticationType requestedAuthType,String hostName,String port,String orgName,NetworkCredential credential,String userId,SecureString password,String domain,String Geo,String claimsHomeRealm,Boolean useSsl,Boolean useUniqueInstance,OrganizationDetail orgDetail,String clientId,Uri redirectUri,PromptBehavior promptBehavior,OrganizationWebProxyClientAsync externalOrgWebProxyClient,String certificateThumbPrint,StoreName certificateStoreName,X509Certificate2 certificate,Uri instanceUrl,Boolean isCloned,Boolean useDefaultCreds,Version incomingOrgVersion,ILogger externalLogger,String tokenCacheStorePath)
at Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.ServiceClient..ctor(Uri instanceUrl,String clientId,String clientSecret,Boolean useUniqueInstance,ILogger logger)
at CEP.CustomerTimeline.API.Repositories.DynamicsRepository..ctor(IOptions`1 options)
at D:\a\1\s\CEP.CustomerTimeline.API\Repositories\DynamicsRepository.cs : 19at lambda_method(Closure )at DryIoc.Scope.TryGetOrAdd(ImMap`1 items,Int32 id,CreateScopedValue createValue,Int32 disposalOrder)
at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs : 7856at DryIoc.Scope.GetOrAdd(Int32 id,CreateScopedValue createValue,Int32 disposalOrder)
at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs : 7841at lambda_method(Closure )
at DryIoc.Scope.TryGetOrAdd(ImMap`1 items,Int32 id,CreateScopedValue createValue,Int32 disposalOrder)
at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs : 7856at DryIoc.Scope.GetOrAdd(Int32 id,CreateScopedValue createValue,Int32 disposalOrder)
at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs : 7841at lambda_method(Closure )
at DryIoc.Scope.TryGetOrAdd(ImMap`1 items,Int32 id,CreateScopedValue createValue,Int32 disposalOrder)
at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs : 7856at DryIoc.Scope.GetOrAdd(Int32 id,CreateScopedValue createValue,Int32 disposalOrder)
at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs : 7841at lambda_method(Closure )
at DryIoc.Scope.TryGetOrAdd(ImMap`1 items,Int32 id,CreateScopedValue createValue,Int32 disposalOrder)
at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs : 7856
at DryIoc.Scope.GetOrAdd(Int32 id,CreateScopedValue createValue,Int32 disposalOrder)
at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs : 7841at lambda_method(Closure )
at DryIoc.Scope.TryGetOrAdd(ImMap`1 items,Int32 id,CreateScopedValue createValue,Int32 disposalOrder)
at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs : 7856at DryIoc.Scope.GetOrAdd(Int32 id,CreateScopedValue createValue,Int32 disposalOrder)
at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs : 7841at lambda_method(Closure ,IResolverContext )
at DryIoc.Container.ResolveAndCacheDefaultFactoryDelegate(Type serviceType,IfUnresolved ifUnresolved)
at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs : 225at DryIoc.Container.DryIoc.IResolver.Resolve(Type serviceType,IfUnresolved ifUnresolved)
at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.cs : 196
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.DependencyInjection.ScopedServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
at D:\a\_work\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\ScopedServiceProvider.cs : 25
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp,Type type,Type requiredBy,Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)at lambda_method(Closure ,IServiceProvider ,Object[] )
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultJobActivator.CreateInstance[T](IServiceProvider serviceProvider) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\DefaultJobActivator.cs : 42
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultJobActivator.CreateInstance[T](IFunctionInstanceEx functionInstance) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\DefaultJobActivator.cs : 32
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ActivatorInstanceFactory`1.<>c__DisplayClass1_1.<.ctor>b__0(IFunctionInstanceEx i)
at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\ActivatorInstanceFactory.cs : 20
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ActivatorInstanceFactory`1.Create(IFunctionInstanceEx functionInstance) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\ActivatorInstanceFactory.cs : 26
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.CreateInstance(IFunctionInstanceEx functionInstance) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.cs : 44
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ParameterHelper.Initialize() at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs : 793
at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryExecuteAsync(IFunctionInstance functionInstance,CancellationToken cancellationToken) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs : 104
```

I have seen posts regarding this error when using .NET Framework NuGets, the solution from them are either not applicable or have not worked. I am no expert when it comes to dynamics, my main focus are on integrations so I am at a loss here.

The error occurs when the applications FunctionStartup is running and the repository class, with the connection, is initiated. The connection is done with a scoped lifetime and the same connection is used for all operations towards Dyncamics (I have tried to use one connection per entity as well).

Observations I have made so far:

- The earlybound seems to have something to do with the issue, since if I move over to latebound and delete the earlybound files, the issue dissapears. But I have other solutions using the earlybound in combination with ServiceClient that is working fine
- The issue seems to be related with the dynamics instance that it connects to as well, as it does not happen for our DEV environment, but occurs in SIT
- Removing the type that is causing the issue causes the same error but for a different type
- It works locally, it is not until I deploy it to my function app that the crash occurs
- A simple restart of the function app will resolve the issue

My reflection is that the earlybound is conflicting with some other component as removing it removes the issue. It is the unknown component that I am looking for and part of me is looking towards dynamics, as it works in one environment and not the other and it is always the same environment it works for.

Any help or insight into this would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if there are further questions on this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ---> A proxy type with the name msdyncrm_GetReactions has been defined by another assembly.

You are correct, that this is the relevant part of the error.
That that you're not seeing it locally, and or you're not seeing it on the restart of a function indicates that you're dynamically loading a lib during runtime. ( are you? )

if so that lib has the same types as the root function has + the assembly attribute

```
[assembly: Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ProxyTypesAssemblyAttribute()]
```

That attribute causes the client to attempt to load the types of that assembly into the type mapper used by the client.

its only usefull if your using Linq operations based on the organization service context.

if your not using linq, the easiest way to fix this is to remove the assembly attribute above.

Comment: I am, but it is not from something I have implemented, rather it comes from the Earlybound that I have generated, the CRMContext, which I use for the LINQ querries. But it is only the earlybound that does this, so is it conflicting with itself or is there another part of the solution that it is conflicting with?

Comment: it would be conflicting with another instance of itself ( or you have linked the type twice in the compile?)

Comment: Nope, I have not linked it twice to my knowledge. But I have just discarded the loading of the types done in the CRMContext and stopped using LINQ statements since I moved over to using ServiceClient anyways.